# php регулярка - вывести имя

Tags: php

знатоки!

Такой вопрос - имеется запись в базе такого формата "хххх   Иванов Иван Иванович" - необходимо вытащить имя, проблема в том, что в некоторых случаях запись бывает такого формата "Иванов Иван Иванович", т.е. без номера вначале, подскажите, пожалуйста, универсальное решение задачи

Comment: Что может быть вместо xxxx? Что угодно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужно только имя, то можно фамилию слить с начальными символами и если что, раскрасить фамилию уже второй регуляркой или сабстрингом, примерно так:

```
$re = '/^(.+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)$/m';
$str = 'хххх Иванов Иван Иванович
Иванов Иван Иванович';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно!

Comment: @SyntaxWEB 6stPROD WowSuite, можете еще мой вариант попробовать

Answer (score 2):

```
'/^.*?\h+\K[А-Яа-я]+(?=\h+[А-Яа-я]+$)/m'
```

[См. демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/3HP06e/1)

Answer (score 2):

Если перед Ф.И.О находятся только числа *(или ничего)*, то можно их обрезать одной строкой кода:

```
$str = '123 Иванов Иван Иванович';

echo preg_replace('~(?:\d+\h)?(?=(?:\pL+\h*)+)~u', '', $str);
```

Результат:

```
Иванов Иван Иванович
```

---

[Смотреть демо](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/17d28af9a622553b675d562528df7263c4aaf597)

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант необходимый результат можно получить с помощью sql-запроса. Я не уверен, что это вариант будет самый производительный, однако это вариант

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(`name`, '^[^ ]+', '') as name FROM `table` WHERE `name` REGEXP '[^ ]+ Иванов Иван Иванович'
```

Замените "name" и "table" на свои. Кстати, если вы скажите, что вместо хххх может быть, конкретизировать регулярное выражение. Например, если 4 цифры:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(`name`, '^[0-9]{4}', '') as name FROM `table` WHERE `name` REGEXP '[0-9]{4} Иванов Иван Иванович'
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно просто вывести предпоследнее слово

```
echo reset( array_slice( explode(" ", $str), -2, 1));
```

Или более универсальный вариант

```
$str = '123 Иванов Иван Иванович';

$str=preg_replace('/[^А-Яа-я \-]/ui', '', $str); # убераем всё кроме букв, пробелов, тире
$fio=explode(' ',trim($str)); # получаем массив [Ф,И,O]

echo $fio[1]; # выводим имя
```

Answer (score 1):

Найти индекс Первой буквы в верхнем регистре и с нее сделать substr

```
$a = "123443 Вася";

$upperIndex = -1;
for(int $i = 0; $i < strlen($a); $i++)
{
    if(ctype_upper($a[$i]))
    {
        $upperIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}

if( $upperIndex != -1 )
{
    $userName = substr($a, $upperIndex);
}
```

Comment: я плохо знаком с регулярками, не могли бы Вы мне помочь?